# NetBeans Platform App Main class doesn't start

Tags: netbeans, platform

Is there any way to set which class should be started when I start a NetBeans Platform Application? Unfortunately I'm not a Netbeans expert.
There is a legacy project I have to deal with. It's a Netbeans Platform App with several modules. As far as I know, during the startup that class will be -let's say'- the main class, which extends ModuleInstall. Usually the name of this class is Installer.

My problem is that, I have this Installer class which extends ModuleInstall, it implements all the required methods, but if I start the project, other window appears instead of this one.

Do you have any idea what should I do to get the proper class invoked at start?

Thanks in advance!

```
>Log Session: Wednesday, February 5, 2014 3:05:27 PM CET
>System Info: 
  Product Version         =  (app) v1.3.3 20138
  Operating System        = Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.7.0_25; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.25-b01; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_25-b16
  Java Home               = D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (app); Cp1252
  Home Directory          = C:\Users\john
  Current Directory       = D:\john\Projects\NetBeans Projects\Java1.6\app
  User Directory          = D:\john\Projects\NetBeans Projects\Java1.6\app\build\testuserdir
  Cache Directory         = D:\john\Projects\NetBeans Projects\Java1.6\app\build\testuserdir\var\cache
  Installation            = D:\john\Projects\NetBeans Projects\Java1.6\app\build\cluster
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jfr.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\classes;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
  Application Classpath   = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\boot.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\org-openide-util-lookup.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\org-openide-util.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\boot_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\boot_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\boot_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\boot_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\lib\dt.jar;D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\lib\tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\core.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\core_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\core_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\core_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\core_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar;D:\john\Projects\NetBeans Projects\Java1.6\app\build\cluster\core\locale\core_app.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
    org.openide.util.lookup [8.22.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.util [8.33.2 201312091611]
    org.openide.modules [7.39.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.filesystems [8.8.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.api.annotations.common/1 [1.21.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.awt [7.59.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.api.progress/1 [1.35.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.dialogs [7.32.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.nodes [7.36.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.windows [6.65.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup/1 [1.33.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.text [6.58.2 201312091611]
    org.netbeans.swing.tabcontrol [1.46.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.swing.outline [1.27.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.explorer [6.54.1 201312091611]
    org.openide.actions [6.32.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.queries/1 [1.36.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.loaders [7.51.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.io [1.42.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.swing.plaf [1.34.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.spi.quicksearch [1.20.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.bootstrap/1 [2.63.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.core.startup/1 [1.51.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.settings/1 [1.42.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.sampler [1.7.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui [1.26.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.print [7.19.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.keyring [1.17.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.core/2 [3.43.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.options.api/1 [1.36.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap [1.28.2 201312091611]
    org.netbeans.modules.masterfs/2 [2.44.3 201312091611]
    org.netbeans.libs.jna/1 [1.31.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.windows [1.7.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.keyring.fallback [1.1.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.keyring.impl [1.14.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.javahelp/1 [2.34.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup.impl/1 [1.24.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.libs.osgi [1.15.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.libs.jna.platform/1 [1.1.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.libs.felix [2.9.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.core.windows/2 [2.66.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.core.ui/1 [1.38.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.core.output2/1 [1.34.3 201312091611]
    org.netbeans.core.network [1.1.2 201312091611]
    org.netbeans.core.netigso [1.23.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.core.nativeaccess/1 [1.23.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.core.multiview/1 [1.36.1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.core.multitabs [1.3.3.1 1 201310111528]
    org.netbeans.core.io.ui/1 [1.23.1 201310111528]
    com.awst.lib [1.0 140205]
    org.customer.package.name.core.domain [1.0 140205]
    org.customer.package.name.core.appexception [1.0 140205]
    org.customer.package.name.core.appservices [1.0 140205]
    org.customer.package.name.core.datamodel [1.0 140205]
    org.customer.package.name.common.userinterface [1.0 140205]
    org.customer.package.name.ui.workflow [1.0 140205]
    org.customer.package.name.ui.testevaulationreport [1.0 140205]
    org.customer.package.name.ui.stationhierarchy [1.0 140205]
    org.customer.package.name.ui.datefilter [1.0 140205]
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy resolver: Windows
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.windows.WindowsNetworkProxy]: Windows system proxy resolver: auto detect
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy reloading succeeded.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy - mode: direct
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy: falled to default (corect if direct mode went before)
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Toolbars/ marked with the position attribute: [app], but some are: [Memory, Standard.xml]
INFO [org.netbeans.ui.metrics.laf]: USG_LOOK_AND_FEEL
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
    -Dnetbeans.logger.console=true
    -ea
    -Dlog4j.configuration=org/ctbto/idc/rn/app/core/appservices/log4jconfig.xml
    -Xms256m
    -Xmx512m
    -Xverify:none
    -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
    -Djdk.home=D:\john\app\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
    -splash:D:\john\Projects\NetBeans Projects\Java1.6\app\build\testuserdir\var\cache\splash.png
    -Dnetbeans.home=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform
    -Dnetbeans.user=D:\john\Projects\NetBeans Projects\Java1.6\app\build\testuserdir
    -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=D:\john\Projects\NetBeans Projects\Java1.6\app\build\testuserdir\var\log\heapdump.hprof
    -Dsun.awt.keepWorkingSetOnMinimize=true
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=D:\john\Projects\NetBeans Projects\Java1.6\app\build\cluster;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform
    exit
Compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
Heap memory usage: initial 256.0MB maximum 455.1MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 23.2MB maximum 130.0MB
Garbage collector: PS Scavenge (Collections=2 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: PS MarkSweep (Collections=0 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=4107 total loaded=4107 unloaded 0
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 12,866,506,752
INFO [null]: Total physical memory 12,866,506,752
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Menu/Window/ marked with the position attribute: [org-customer-app-ui-datefilter-DateFilterTopComponent.shadow, org-customer-app-ui-stationhierarchy-StationHierarchyAction.shadow, org-customer-app-ui-testevaulationreport-TestEvaluationReportTopComponent.shadow, org-customer-app-ui-workflow-WorkflowTopComponent.shadow], but some are: [org-netbeans-core-io-ui-IOWindowAction.shadow, SwitchToRecentDocumentAction.shadow, Web, Tools, Separator3.instance, ConfigureWindow, org-netbeans-core-windows-actions-ResetWindowsAction.shadow, Separator4.instance, CloseWindowAction.shadow, CloseAllDocumentsAction.shadow, CloseAllButThisAction.shadow, DocumentsAction.shadow]
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.home has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.Clusters.relativeDirsWithHome(Clusters.java:137)
```

Comment: What you want to achieve, show some Swing components or do the other action at the startup?
Right now your Installer class doesn't starts? Which version of Netbeans Platform do you use?

Comment: I finaly solved this. The problem was that I tried to use the latest version of netbeans while the project was created with an older version of Netbeans (7.2). What I had to do is open the project with the right version of Netbeans and compile it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer to your question (although I see you've solved it differently).

However, I would like to answer your question as it stands:

> Is there any way to set which class should be started when I start a
>   NetBeans Platform Application?

Yes, there is.You can provide your own `main` method class to a NetBeans Platform application.

You do this by providing a system property, `netbeans.mainclass` on the command line when you start your application. This must point to your custom main class. The place to define this variable is in your application's `conf` file.

Once you're done doing whatever you want to do in your custom main then you must handover control to the real NetBeans main class.

Here's a short example of such a custom main:

```
public class CustomStartup {

    private static final String NB_MAIN_CLASS = "org.netbeans.core.startup.Main";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // do whatever you need here (e.g. show a custom login form)
        System.out.println("Hello world! I am a custom startup class");


        // once you're done with that, hand control back to NetBeans
        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName(NB_MAIN_CLASS, true, classloader);

        Object mainObject = mainClass.newInstance();
        Method mainMethod = mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[]{String[].class});
        mainMethod.invoke(mainObject, (Object) args);
    }
}
```

It is quite well explained [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqPlatformAppAuthStrategies). (example is from that link)

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Ctrl-1</kbd> to open your **Project** window
2. <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on your project and click on **Properties**
3. Click on the **Run** node from the **Categories** pane on the left, look for **Main Class:** text field on the right then type in the fully qualified name of your main class, or you could just click the **Browse...** button to avoid typo(s).

[image]

If it's a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) project, make sure the `pom.xml` has the following w/in the `/project/build/plugins` element:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass><!--fully qualified name of your main class goes here--></mainClass>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it's not what I'm looking for. What you present in your answer is how to set the main class in case of a Java Application. I need something like this for Netbeans Platform Application, which is not the same. In case of this kind of project the actual main class is inside the runtime container. I have to tell somehow the runtime container which class I want to start.

Comment: @高科技黑手: Nice screenshot! Which tool did you use to make it?

Comment: [Alt+PrintScreen] and paste into GIMP (www.gimp.org), use "Ellipse Select Tool" to select the area(s) I wanted to highlight, then [Ctrl+I] (Select -> Invert) to invert the selections, finally grey out (Color -> Desaturate); hope this helps you :)